# Java: Syntax error on token "else"

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax

Okay, I've looked at quite a few stack overflow questions and quite a few blogs, and still cannot find the answer to this. No, it doesn't look like it is missing braces, has extra semicolons, or any other typo that I am aware of. Why is the 'else' showing an error?

```
// check if myid property is set and create it if not
String subtopicMyId = subtopicNode.hasProperty("myid") ? subtopicNode.getProperty("myid").getString() : "";
if (subtopicMyId.equals("")) {
    // generate new myid and check it against the list of existing IDs until a unique one is generated
    do {
        // generate new myid
        Object topicmyidobj = new Object();
        subtopicMyId = topicmyidobj.toString().split("@")[1].toUpperCase();
    } while ( subtopicMyId.equals("") || existingMyIds.contains(subtopicMyId) );
    // set myid on this node
    subtopicNode.setProperty("myid", subtopicMyId);
    subtopicNode.setProperty("parentid", topicMyId);
    subtopicNode.save();
    // add new myid to list of existsing IDs so that it doesn't get reused
    existingMyIds.add(subtopicMyId);
} else {
    // if subtopic has myid already
    // compare the parentid to the parent myid
    String subtopicParentId = subtopicNode.getProperty("parentid").getString();
    if (!subtopicParentId.equals(topicMyId)) {
        // they don't match
        String subtopicNodePath = subtopicNode.getPath();
        String topicNodePath = topicNode.getPath();
        // find path to topic node that has matching myid to this subtopic's parentid
        // loop through parent nodes
        NodeIterator reorgTopicsIter = compNode.getNodes();
        while (reorgTopicsIter.hasNext()) {
            // loop through parent objects to find a matching myid for parentid
            Node reorgTopicNode = (Node)reorgTopicsIter.next();
            // get the myid property from this node, if it exists, and compare the parentid to it
            String reorgTopicMyId = reorgTopicNode.hasProperty("myid") ? reorgTopicNode.getProperty("myid").getString() : "";
            if (!reorgTopicMyId.equals("")) {
                // parent myid exists and is not blank
                if (reorgTopicMyId.equals(subtopicParentId)) {
                    // parentid does match parent myid
                    String reorgTopicNodePath = reorgTopicNode.getPath();
                    // determine how many parent objects there are
                    int reorgTopicSubtopics = 0;
                    NodeIterator reorgSubtopicsIter = reorgTopicNode.getNodes();
                    while (reorgSubtopicsIter.hasNext()) {
                        Node reorgSubtopicNode = (Node)reorgSubtopicsIter.next();
                        reorgTopicSubtopics++;
                    }
                    // set source to this child object
                    String source = subtopicNode.getPath();
                    // set destination to matching parent object with new child object appended
                    String destination = reorgTopicNodePath + "/subtopic-" + (reorgTopicSubtopics + 1);
                    // create session for move and perform move
                    Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
                    session.move(source, destination);
                    session.save();
                } else {
                    // parentid does not match parent myid.
                    // nothing we need to do here;
                    // it just moves on to check next parent myid.
                }
            } else {
                // parent myid does not exist or is blank
            }
        } else {
            // no more parent objects to loop through, so we need to check if a match was found
            // if no match was found, then parent was deleted or no longer exists, so we need to remove this child
        }
    } else {
        // parentid does match parent myid
    }
}
```

Here is the error in the console:

```
An error occurred at line: 145 in the jsp file: /apps/covidien/components/content/utilities/faq-node-process/faq-node-process.jsp
Syntax error on token "else", delete this token
142:                                 subtopicNode.save();
143:                                 // add new myid to list of existsing IDs so that it doesn't get reused
144:                                 existingMyIds.add(subtopicMyId);
145:                             } else {
146:                                 // if subtopic has myid already
147:                                 // compare the parentid to the parent myid
148:                                 String subtopicParentId = subtopicNode.getProperty("parentid").getString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the number of if and else statement is not same. you have 4 if blocks but 5 else block.

Comment: One of those else blocks goes to a while. I have been under the impression that it is okay to use that kind of syntax. Am I wrong?

Comment: @TyB No, `else` only goes after `if`.

Comment: Hmm... I figured it was bad form, but went along with the advise anyhow. I'll have to change up how I'm handling that loop. I've been thinking of setting a boolean flag that gets marked true if a match is found, and then after the loop, read that flag back, and if it is still false, I know the node has no parent anymore and can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

`else` can't be used after `while`. There's nothing in that `else` block anyway, so it should just be deleted.

There's a lot of redundant code here. My rewrite:

```
// check if myid property is set and create it if not
String subtopicMyId = subtopicNode.getProperty("myid").getString();
if (subtopicMyId == null) {
    // generate new myid and check it against the list of existing IDs until a unique one is generated
    do {
        // generate new myid
        Object topicmyidobj = new Object();
        subtopicMyId = topicmyidobj.toString().split("@")[1].toUpperCase();
    } while ( subtopicMyId.equals("") || existingMyIds.contains(subtopicMyId) );
    // set myid on this node
    subtopicNode.setProperty("myid", subtopicMyId);
    subtopicNode.setProperty("parentid", topicMyId);
    subtopicNode.save();
    // add new myid to list of existsing IDs so that it doesn't get reused
    existingMyIds.add(subtopicMyId);
} else {
    // if subtopic has myid already
    // compare the parentid to the parent myid
    String subtopicParentId = subtopicNode.getProperty("parentid").getString();
    if (!subtopicParentId.equals(topicMyId)) {
        // they don't match
        String subtopicNodePath = subtopicNode.getPath();
        String topicNodePath = topicNode.getPath();
        // find path to topic node that has matching myid to this subtopic's parentid
        // loop through parent nodes
        NodeIterator reorgTopicsIter = compNode.getNodes();
        while (reorgTopicsIter.hasNext()) {
            // loop through parent objects to find a matching myid for parentid
            Node reorgTopicNode = (Node)reorgTopicsIter.next();
            // get the myid property from this node, if it exists, and compare the parentid to it
            String reorgTopicMyId = reorgTopicNode.getProperty("myid").getString();
            if (reorgTopicMyId != null && reorgTopicMyId.equals(subtopicParentId)) {
                // parentid does match parent myid
                String reorgTopicNodePath = reorgTopicNode.getPath();
                // determine how many parent objects there are
                int reorgTopicSubtopics = 0;
                NodeIterator reorgSubtopicsIter = reorgTopicNode.getNodes();
                while (reorgSubtopicsIter.hasNext()) {
                    Node reorgSubtopicNode = (Node)reorgSubtopicsIter.next();
                    reorgTopicSubtopics++;
                }
                // set source to this child object
                String source = subtopicNode.getPath();
                // set destination to matching parent object with new child object appended
                String destination = reorgTopicNodePath + "/subtopic-" + (reorgTopicSubtopics + 1);
                // create session for move and perform move
                Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
                session.move(source, destination);
                session.save();
            } else {
                    // parentid does not match parent myid.
                    // nothing we need to do here;
                    // it just moves on to check next parent myid.
            }
        }
    } else {
        // parentid does match parent myid
    }
}
```

Comment: That else block was going to have some code for deleting the node since no parent with a matching id could be found. It's still a work in progress. The code is very messy, and I've had to leave comments throughout the entire thing to keep track of what I'm doing with it.

Comment: I like the way you redid the if inside the if and removed the ternary. I think I am going to reincorporate that into this code.

Comment: @TyB You can handle that case with `if (!reorgTopicsIter.hasNext()) { ... } else while ...` before the `while` loop concerned.

Answer (score 0):

five `else` with four `if`, not match.
At least number of `if` should more than `else`.